# How to set the contentGravity variable of CALayer to 'resizeAspectFill'?

Tags: ios, swift, quartz-core

I am trying to set the contentGravity variable of a CALayer but I am not quite sure how to do this.  I have tried the following without success:

```
var layer = CAShapeLayer.init()
layer.contentGravity = .resizeAspectFill // This is not recognised
```

My UIImageView presents the image taken from the camera of the phone.  I then use the Vision Framework to detect rectangles, which return the four corner coordinates of the detected rectangle.  I then draw the rectangle in the layer of the UIImageView.  The content mode of the UIIMageView is  'Aspect Fill'.  My rectangle is currently misaligned and i think it has to do with the contentGravity of the layer.  Please see image below:

Rectangle drawn into CAShapelayer:

```
let rec = UIBezierPath.init()
    rec.move(to: CGPoint.init(x: topLeft.x, y: topLeft.y))
    rec.addLine(to: CGPoint.init(x: topRight.x, y: topRight.y))
    rec.addLine(to: CGPoint.init(x: bottomRight.x, y: bottomRight.y))
    rec.addLine(to: CGPoint.init(x: bottomLeft.x, y: bottomLeft.y))
    rec.close()

    self.layer.opacity = 0.4
    self.layer.path = rec.cgPath
    self.layer.lineWidth = 5
    self.layer.strokeColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
    self.layer.frame = self.imgPreViewOutlet.bounds

    self.imgPreViewOutlet.layer.addSublayer(self.layer)
```

[image show misaligned rectangle drawn in the layer of UIImageView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpM3A.png)

Answer (score 2):

There is no purpose in setting the content gravity of a CAShapeLayer, as it will in no way affect how the shape is drawn. Content gravity is meaningful only for a layer with *content*, e.g. a CGImage that is drawn into its `contents` property.

Here's an example where `contentsGravity` matters; same image, same layer size, different content gravity:

[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    do {
        let layer = CALayer()
        layer.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 250, height: 200)
        layer.contents = UIImage(named:"smiley")!.cgImage
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
        layer.contentsGravity = .center
    }
    do {
        let layer = CALayer()
        layer.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 300, width: 250, height: 200)
        layer.contents = UIImage(named:"smiley")!.cgImage
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
        layer.contentsGravity = .resize
    }
}
```

But if we try exactly the same thing with a shape layer, the content gravity makes no difference:

[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    do {
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 250, height: 200)
        layer.path = CGPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20), transform: nil)
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
        layer.contentsGravity = .center
    }
    do {
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 300, width: 250, height: 200)
        layer.path = CGPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20), transform: nil)
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
        layer.contentsGravity = .resize
    }
}
```

Comment: In this instance, i have an image that is a rectangular document and i would like to draw an outline of the document in the CAShapelayer.  If the content mode of the UIImageView is 'Aspect Fill', would i not need to also set the contentGravity of the CAShaplayer? I am using the Vision Frame work which detects rectangles. Please advise? I am currently getting a misalignment and I think it has something to do with the contentGravity of the layer...

Comment: Did you read my answer??? Shape layer does not have contents gravity for the shape. The end. You can’t accomplish this using a shape layer plus contents gravity.